# how to setup log4j to specific file for each error / warning/ info (in grails)

Tags: java, grails, log4j

I am little bit confuse about log4j in grails.

I need to log info into info.log, error into error.log and warning into warning.log

if possible, all the files (info,warning and error) should be placed into web-app/
so that i can do check via internet (vpn)

can someone help me to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using Grails 1.1+, what about:

```
appenders {
    file name:'infoLog', file:'info.log', threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.INFO
    file name:'warnLog', file:'warn.log', threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.WARN
    file name:'errorLog', file:'error.log', threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.ERROR
}

root {
    info 'infoLog','warnLog','errorLog'
}
```

With this configuration, `info.log` will contain all log messages with level INFO and above (ie. INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL), `warn.log` will contain WARN and above, `error.log` will contain ERROR and above.

In the example above, I have configured the root logger, so everything (including Grails core) gets logged. But of course, you can configure this more fine-grained if you want.

Hope this helps.

Comment: is " file name" type with space ?

Comment: The code is correct. It defines a FileAppender ("file") with the name 'infoLog' (name: 'infoLog') which writes log message to the 'info.log' file (file: 'info.log'). Have a look at the custom appender section in the docs: http://grails.org/doc/1.1.x/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.1.2%20Logging

Comment: in my previous configuration I have this 
appender.logfile = "org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender"

how to put this on each so that I can have DailyRollingFileAppender
thank you !!